# How to analyze property-values inside complex repetative patterns using Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a model containing repetative patterns. Let's assume each pattern has a structure like `(:A{name:<name>)-[:ab]->(:B)-[:bc]->(:C{value:<value>)` which is a tree structure with only one A-node (i.e.: number of C-nodes >= number of B-nodes >= 1 = number of A-nodes). The number of B-nodes and C-nodes can be different for each pattern. I want to analyze for each A-node the property-values of its related C-nodes (e.g. I would like to find min/max values in all C-nodes related to the single A-node inside each pattern).

- As there are many A-nodes (>1000) in my model, I need an efficient solution.
- I would like to avoid apoc-solutions, if possible (but if the usage of apoc should be necessary/recommended, I would try).

At first, I tried something like this:

`MATCH(:A)-[:ab]->(:B)-[:bc]->(:C)
WITH A,B,C ORDER BY A.name
return A.name,C.value`

The results show for each value of C the name of the related a node. For the next step I thought about creating two lists by collecting A.name and C.value and doing some filter-operations. But I think there must be a smarter way to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you want to find min/max in C for each A, or for a min/max across all C find corresponding A?

Comment: I want to find min/max in C for each A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypher has several [built-in aggregation functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/), including min and max.

Your query is already very close:

```
MATCH (a:A)-[:ab]->(:B)-[:bc]->(c:C)
RETURN a.name,max(c.value),min(c.value)
ORDER BY a.name
```

You might want to have an index on A(name) for faster sort.

Comment: That works. An other case is that I need to identify for this model wether a list I get out of C.values is ordered for each A. I think this is more difficult ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57963219/how-to-identify-a-sorted-list

Comment: What list? c.value contains a list? List collected from c.value? You need to provide more details and likely it's new question..